# Emberjs equivalent of root to: "something" in Rails route

Tags: ember.js

In emberjs routes, I have

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('projects');
});
```

*about* page shows up when I hit `/about` and *projects* page shows up when I hit `/projects`.

How do you make the about page show up even in `/` as well as `/about`?

Rails equivalent of would be something like

```
root to: "pages#about"
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
get 'projects', to: 'pages#projects'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ember generates a IndexRoute mapping to '/'

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  // By default ember generates a IndexRoute mapping to '/'
  // this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('projects');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo('about');
  }
});
```

So you can override the `beforeModel` from `IndexRoute` to transition to `about` route.

Comment: I didn't specify in the question, but it would be better if the url isn't redirected to 'about'. is there a way to keep using '/' as url, but show 'about' content?

Comment: You can use `this.resource('about', { path: '/' });` but you will lost the `/about`. I think that in the moment isn't possible to map a route for two urls, like: `this.resource('about', { path: '/' }); this.resource('about', { path: '/about' });`